# Is there really no iscsi support in Ubuntu Core 20?

Tags: ubuntu-core, iscsi

I am trying to use ubuntu core 20 as a iscsi initiator.
iscsiadm is not available. Documentation at [ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/core/docs) has no information about iscsi.
Is there really no iscsi support in ubuntu core 20?

Comment: open-iscsi should work (not tested), see (for more info): https://manjaro.site/how-to-connect-to-iscsi-volume-from-ubuntu-20-04/

Comment: Are you asking if iscsi compatibility has been removed from the Ubuntu 20 kernel? Or are you asking if anybody has made Snap packages that include iscsiadm? Or are you asking why you cannot use the `open-iscsi` deb package on Ubuntu Core?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am asking how I can connect to iscsi without iscsiadm which is not available for ubuntu core 20.

Comment: @Luuk: open-iscsi is not available for ubuntu core 20.